# Calculating $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{[1, \infty)} \frac{n \sin(\frac{x}{n}) }{x^3}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I want to compute $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{[1, \infty)} \frac{n \sin(\frac{x}{n}) }{x^3}\,dx$$
I tried to use Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.
It holds:  $$  |f_n(x)|=  |  \frac{n \sin(\frac{x}{n}) }{x^3}\ |  \leq  \frac{n x/n}{x^3} =\frac{1}{x^2}     $$
The last function is lebesgue integrable.You can compute $ f_n \rightarrow \frac{x}{x^3} = \frac{1}{x^2}   $ So $f_n $ converges pointwise. 
Therefore the theorem says I can swap limit and integral. So I get $$ \int_{[1, \infty)} \frac{1}{x^2} dx $$
Now I think there is a theorem, that says: If the improper-Riemann-integral over f converges, f is also lebesgue integrable. This is the case. I only don't know, wether the values of these integrals are the same?

I would say: $$ \int_{[1, \infty)} \frac{1}{x^2} dx = \int_{1}^ {\infty} \frac{1}{x^2} dx = 1  $$
Is this right?

Comment: Yes. It is right. (Any absolutley convergent Riemann-integrable function is Lebesge integrable and vice-versa)

Comment: @TitoEliatron: The values are the same?

Comment: *If the improper-Riemann-integral over f converges, f is also lebesgue integrable* This is false. See $\sin(x)/x$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral . However, it is true for positive functions. In that cases both integrals agree. It follows from the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: @mlainz Ok in this case it is true, because $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is a positive function. But I cannot say something about the values of these integrals.

Comment: @mlainz : You mean the theorem of beppo Levi?

Comment: @Steven33 yes (I didn't know that name for it)

Comment: If a function is Riemann integrable on a bounded interval, then it is also Lebesgue integrable and both integrals agree

Comment: @mlainz: So I don't  have to argue with Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem. There is only left to show, that $f_n$ is  monotonous increasing?

Comment: Pass to the limit and use monotone convergence

Comment: Take $f_n = f * 1_{[1,n]}$

Comment: I don't know what are you aiming at?

Comment: @mlainz The limit of $f_n $ is $\frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: @mlainz it is true for absolutly convergent integrals.

Comment: @TitoEliatron: Ok but you do not know wether the integrals are the same?

Comment: @Steven33 They are both the same (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral#Improper_Riemann_integrals_and_Lebesgue_integrals)

Comment: @TitoEliatron: Why is that? The thereom only says something about existence?

Comment: @Steven33 "both exist. Furthermore, f is Lebesgue integrable on [a, ∞), and its Lebesgue integral is equal to its improper Riemann integral.·

Comment: @TitoEliatron: I see. Thank you:)

Comment: @TitoEliatron: Do you know, what I have to do with $f_n =  f  \cdot 1_{[1,n]} $

Comment: @Steven33 i think it is unnecessary here.

Comment: @TitoEliatron: Thank you very much: I appreciate your help:)